# Could not fetch dataset "analytics_xxxxxxxxx"

Tags: google-bigquery

After integration Big Query with Firebase Analytics passed more than one day, but the analytics data is still not imported. Clicking on view ("your raw events in BigQuery") button in Firebase Events section, Big Query opens, but I get the error message "Could not fetch dataset "analytics_xxxxxxxxx".

Firebase Free Plan.
Big Query Sandbox.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait more than one day. In my case, I have been waiting for 3 day. Eventually, I can import data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can import data after 18hr and get the data every 24hr automatically as expected.